# Windows 10's Explorer.exe crashes every few minutes

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

I'm running Windows 10 64-bit upgraded from Windows 7. Open explorer.exe windows just disappear, and the system logs show they've crashed. Here's the report:

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.10240.16431, time stamp: 0x55c9bd76

Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.10240.16430, time stamp: 0x55c59f92

Exception code: 0xc000071f

Fault offset: 0x00000000000a803b

Faulting process id: 0x32ee8

Faulting application start time: 0x01d10b498b8e0dee

Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe

Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll

Report Id: 83ec15c6-49a7-495c-a0c5-4a1ad68a0738

Faulting package full name: 

Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I've run the usual disable-faulty-handlers routine with ShellExView, to no avail.

Also, the events seem to be quite random. The windows do not need to be in focus to crash, and sometimes they hold themselves fine for 10+ minutos. Some other times, as little as a minute is enough for them to close.

How can I discover what's going on?

Comment: Until this Windows 10 issue is resolved, you you might try an alternative file manager such as Q-Dir and Total Commander. See http://alternativeto.net/software/q-dir/. This will not help with explorer.exe as a background process (e.g. desktop display), though. It will, however, show if the issue is with file display.

Comment: I use [xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/) instead of Explorer. Even the free version is much better than Explorer. Of course Explorer is still used for the desktop and taskbar as pointed out in the above comment.

Comment: capture and share a crash dump, so that I can look at it with a debugger: http://pastebin.com/WACz5GBU

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks, gonna try them as well.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That'd be awesome! But the links on the pastebin aren't working (something like "Sorry, an error has occurred.")

I manage to find this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

But I'm not sure if I'm supposed to go full dump or mini dump. Or about flags.

Comment: tr again. The links work for me.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's quite embarrasing: I managed to set the WER configs, but explorer refused to crash in the last two days. I'll keep it up, and if it ever happens again (it happened a month ago and vanished just like this), I'll make the dump available.